# Do not show the label if it is outside the map canvas #42990

Tags: qgis, labeling

I wrote on the Qgis forum, but they suggested to to write here too.
I'm having this problem on Qgis 3.16.6 that in 3.10.8  there wasn't.

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/42990

Can you give me a solution or any idea to avoid this?

---

I'm using labels set in a way that their positions are determined by X,Y coordinates, because I need them in THAT position to avoid overlap with TENs of other labels (not included in the pic below to simplify the explanation of this behavior).
I created a map windows in Print Layout as you can see in A

[image]

If I shift the map windows content it could happens that some labels are outside the borders, and they should disappear from the map window bacause their X,Y position, but Qgis still shows them if the related geometry is still present in the map window, and put without even trying to prevent them from overlapping each other (LIP333 along North border, LIP88A, LIP88B along south border). and also in way it seems around the centroid of the visible polygon (LIR82 along East border, LIP3 along West border), all regardless of the chosen positioning mode (Horizontal, offset, etc...)

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this behavior? I'd like to let labels out of the map window if their positions aren't included. What is the use of setting coordinates if Qgis does what it wants?

Comment: Can you provide your exact label settings?

Comment: how can I attach a zip with the sample?

Comment: Were you able to solve it? If not could you attach a screenshot of the label styling and placement setting?

Comment: No... this problem still persists..... I tried every combination with styling setting, but nothing works. The only way to avoid is to have any portion of polygon in the map.